# Lib not found (I have to add it every time I open the project)

Tags: ios9, static-libraries, xcode7

I got this error every time I reopen my project, I have checked the Building setting ,search path ,everything seems fine.
I have to  delete the lib ,and add it again ...

It's driving me crazy..
[The error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3Dso.jpg)

Comment: Looks like those `-L` options are the cause (for example `Framwork` isn't how it's spelt, is it).  Why are they wrong?

Comment: @trojanfoe  This is a third-party framework ,I made a demo before I added it to my project . The demo works fine (it also have the -L options warning )..

Answer (score 0):

I delete all frameworks which contains the lib ,only left one . and clear the search path , reset all the stuff , and added it again . Problem solved.